# Search engine misinterprets search query: "-cookie -cookies"

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I believe I found a bug in the search engine.  The following [query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q="expire"+-cookie+-cookies):

```
"expire" -cookie -cookies
```

is misinterpreted as:

> results found containing s "expire"  and not containing

Now the query lists results containing both the letter "s"  and the word "expire".
(Note that the words not contained are not listed.  That's a separate issue, although it doesn't
seem to affect the search results; trying `"expire"` and `"expire" -cookie` appears to work correctly.)

Comment: [easy to reproduce](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btest%5D+-something+-somethingx)

Comment: and [this search](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=-asdf+-asdfpie) (`-asdf -asdfpie`) and [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=pie) (`pie`) are identical.

Comment: This search doesn't really make much sense, since `-cookie` will exclude `-cookies` anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Our parsing logic didn't account for substrings existing in subsequent search terms (ie. "cookies" contains "cookie").

This is now fixed and will be with you in the next build.